# Upload file to BackBlaze

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, backblaze

I have a form with 2 file inputs and I need to choose a file and upload it to backblaze. This is the function that I created in order to upload the picture. I pass as a parameter the path that I retrieved from the form.

```
public function uploadImage($path)
    {
        try {
            //get file name
            $fileName = $path->getClientOriginalName();

            // get file contents
            $contents = file_get_contents($path->getRealPath());

            //upload to Backblaze
            Storage::disk('b2')->put($fileName, $contents);
            dd('OK! STORED SUCESSFULLY');
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            dd($e);
        }
    }
```

I got the next error

```
ErrorException {#2033 ▼ // app\Http\Livewire\quote\NewQuote.php:89
  #message: "filesize(): Filename contains null byte"
  #code: 0
  #file: "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Dev\CRM\vendor\marcandreappel\flysystem-backblaze\src\BackblazeAdapter.php"
  #line: 45
  #severity: E_WARNING
  trace: {▶}
}
```

Comment: Not sure how exactly `filesize` comes into play, when this is about _creating_ a file. Have you checked what value your `$fileName` actually contains yet? (Inspect in a real debugger, or make a debug output with `urlencode` applied, so that you can see which bytes values are where from the percent encoding.)

Comment: I added a dd($fileName) just after `$fileName = $path->getClientOriginalName()` and the result is the actual name of the file I want to upload "addQuote_view.png" // app\Http\Livewire\quote\NewQuote.php:81``

Comment: I doubt that `dd` would actually be able to show you if there way a null byte anywhere in there. (I mentioned `urlencode` for a reason.) But it is rather unlikely that you get a null byte in the file name with a normal upload that hasn't been actively manipulated by anyone, so that is probably not it to begin with here. You should first of all follow that trace from your exeception output a little deeper, to see where that error actually occurs.

Comment: Does somebody confirm if the structure `Storage::disk('b2')->put($fileName, $contents);` correct? Accordingly to backblaze the usage should be \Storage::disk('b2')->put('filename.txt', 'My important content'); but not sure being passing the right parameters.